# "Type" in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What's does `type Props = {};` mean in React Native project?

It's used in `extends Component<Props>`

Is it flow?
But I don't see flow in dependecies.

Visual Studio Code says it's an error. But everything compiles without problems.

Comment: Looks like TypeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a TypeScript code. extends Component means that your class/ component props will have to conform with that Props type.

For example,

```
type Props = {
  name: string
}

class Example extends Component<Props> {
...
}
```

Later, when you want to use that component, you should put the props like this

```
<Example name='test'/>
```

If not, TypeScript will give you a compile error.